# How to verify if subquery is correct?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery, syntax-error, in-clause

I have two tables:

- `SupplierLocation` with columns `Id | SupplierId | ThirdPartyId`
- `Supplier` with columns `Id | Company`

We are using SQL Server 2008. I am trying to correct some badly written queries. For example, the following query runs without throwing an error, even though there is an incorrect column name in the subquery (Supplier table does not have ThirdPartyId):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SupplierLocation 
WHERE SupplierId IN (SELECT ThirdPartyId 
                     FROM Supplier 
                     WHERE Id = @id)
```

Is there a way to check that in a query like this the subquery is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Run the subquery to see what results it returns?  Reverse IN/NOT IN to see if counts are affected as you'd expect.

Comment: There must be a ThirdPartyId column in the SupplierLocation table which makes the SQL valid even if it's absurd. There's no way to detect that other than knowing the data model and knowing what the queries are supposed to do.

Comment: @JC. - There is such a column - see the first bullet point in the question.

Comment: Right. Well there's the explanation of why the SQL validates. But there's still no magic way of finding syntactically valid, but functionally broken SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases and qualify the column names.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SupplierLocation as SL
WHERE SL.SupplierId IN (SELECT S.ThirdPartyId 
                     FROM Supplier as S
                     WHERE S.Id = @id)
```

It is perfectly legitimate to include data from various sources in subqueries:

```
SELECT *, ( select Id + ThirdParty + @Id from Supplier where Id = @Id ) as GuessWhat
FROM SupplierLocation as SL
WHERE SL.SupplierId IN (SELECT S.ThirdPartyId 
                     FROM Supplier as S
                     WHERE S.Id = @id)
```

If you aren't explicit about the sources then you may be surprised to find what SQL Server can resolve.  It is good practice whenever you use JOINs to qualify all column names.

The Parse tool in SSMS will detect some, but not all, errors.  It is a handy starting point.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too. There are a big amounts of scripts that we need to go over and verify the fields. Correcting them right now manually and also adding aliases is the solution. This way, if somebody changes a column name in the future and does not make the change in the stored procedure there will be a syntax error. Without aliases, the code is syntactically correct and will run, which is not good.

Comment: It might help cut through some of the work to load the scripts in a good text editor like Notepad++ and do some regex searching to identify sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

While not a universal solution to this issue, the example provided can be rewritten such that similar mistakes are caught by the query compiler.

One approach is to qualify column names.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SupplierLocation 
WHERE SupplierId IN (SELECT Supplier.ThirdPartyId 
    FROM Supplier 
    WHERE Id = @id)
```

Another is to use where exists instead of where in

```
SELECT * 
FROM SupplierLocation 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM Supplier 
    WHERE ID = SupplierID
    AND ID = @ID)
```

(Of course in this example the subquery isn't even required. One could just check the SupplierID column against the @ID variable directly)

Comment: Thanks JC, this is a similar solution to HABO's and also what I was thinking too, to qualify the columns. I think we will go for it.

Comment: Actually the WHERE EXISTS isn't any safer than WHERE IN when it comes to using the wrong column names. Qualified column names are the best option imo.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS` is probably slightly safer as the unqualified `WHERE ID=ID` is more obviously wrong than `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID`

Answer (score 0):

In a word: no - at least, no *simple* way.

If the code runs without throwing an error (but you happen to know that the output is incorrect) then there is an error in the application logic.

If the code runs without throwing an error and you don't *know* whether it's working correctly, there is no magic wand you can wave to validate it.

This is what testing is for: to check that code that runs is working correctly.

Code reviews can also help in this aim.

Answer (score -1):

This should not happen but I could guess at some reasons why it might happen:

1. `SupplierLocation` is empty so the query optimizer compiles a plan that doesn't include the subquery at all.
2. You're only testing with `@id` values that don't exist in `Supplier` so the query optimizer knows that the subquery will always return no records and thus never gets as far as trying to extract a nonexistant column.
3. The server is somehow using a cached plan (an old version) that does not mention the nonexistent column.

It seems much more likely that an error is in fact occuring but you're not seeing it for some reason.

Comment: If the ThirdPartyId is in the SupplierLocation table then the subquery is returning a rowset containing the same value repeatedly. If ThirdPartyId column happens to equal the SupplierId column then the query will return those rows. Otherwise it will return none. But the query is still syntactically valid.

Comment: Yes, I missewd that possibility. That is the most likely situation.

Comment: None of these are real possibilities. SQL Server does not evaluate `1` and `2` at compile time (other than to get an estimated number of rows) It compiles plans that will still be valid even if rows are inserted into and deleted from the tables. RE: `3` if there is a schema change then all related cached plans are automatically dropped.